# Improve code quality while utilizing Guzzle in Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am new with laravel so please don't be harsh.

I am bulding a simple web which connects to an external API(several endpoints) via Guzzle,fetching some data,cleaning them and storing them.

At the moment -and from one endpoint- i have something the following Job:

```
public function handle(Client $client)
{
        try {
            $request= $client->request('GET', 'https://api.url./something', [
                'headers' => [
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key'=> env("FOOTBALL_API_KEY"),
                    'Accept'     => 'application/json'
                ]
            ]);
            $request = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            foreach ($request as $array=>$val) {
                foreach ($val['leagues'] as $id) {
                    League::firstOrCreate(collect($id)->except(['coverage'])->toArray());
                }
            }
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
        };
}
```

Therefore i would like some code recommendations, how can i make my code better from design point of view.

My thoughts are:

a)Bind Guzzle as `service provider`.
b)use a design pattern for implementing calls to endpoints.`URI` builder maybe?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

**May the force be with you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Detailed feedback

Some pointers specific to the provided code itself:

- A guzzle client `request` returns a response, which does not match the name of the parameter you assign it to
- Calls to `json_decode` can fail in which case they'll return `null`. In terms of defensive programming it's good to check for those fail cases
- Your case makes some assumptions about the data in the response. It's best to check if the response is in the actual format you expect before using it.
- You catch all `GuzzleExceptions`, but do nothing in those cases. I think you could improve this by either:

  - Logging the exception
  - Throwing another exception which you will catch at a class, calling the `handle()` method
  - Both of the options above
- You could choose to inject the api key, rather than fetching it directly via the `env()` method.  This will prevent issues described in the [warning block here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#configuration-caching)

## General feedback

It feels like your code is mixing responsibilities, which is considered bad practice. The `handle()` method now does the following:

- Send API requests
- Decode API requests
- Validate API responses
- Parse API responses
- Create models

You could consider moving some or all of these to separate classes, like so:

- `ApiClient` which is responsible for sending out requests
- `ResponseDecoder` which is responsible for turning a response into `\stdClass`
- `ResponseValidator` which is responsible for checking if the response has the expected data structure
- `RepsonseParser` which is responsible for turning the response `\stdClass` into collections
- `LeagueFactory` which is responsible for turning collections into `League` models

One could argue that the first four classes should be put into a single class called `ApiClient`. That's purely up to you.

So in the end you would come up with something like this:

```
<?php


namespace App\Example;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LeagueApiHandler
{
    /**
     * @var ApiClient
     */
    private $apiClient;
    /**
     * @var ResponseDecoder
     */
    private $decoder;
    /**
     * @var ResponseValidator
     */
    private $validator;
    /**
     * @var ResponseParser
     */
    private $parser;
    /**
     * @var LeagueFactory
     */
    private $factory;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        ApiClient $apiClient,
        ResponseDecoder $decoder,
        ResponseValidator $validator,
        ResponseParser $parser,
        LeagueFactory $factory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->apiClient = $apiClient;
        $this->decoder = $decoder;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->apiClient->send();
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->logger->error('Unable to send api request', $e->getMessage());
            return;
        };

        try {
            $decodedResponse = $this->decoder->decode($response);
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->logger->error('Unable to decode api response');
            return;
        };

        if (!$this->validator->isValid($decodedResponse)) {
            $this->logger->error('Unable to decode api response');
            return;
        }

        $collections = $this->parser->toCollection($decodedResponse);
        foreach ($collections as $collection) {
            $this->factory->create($collection);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Example;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiClient
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiKey;

    public function __construct(Client $client, string $apiKey)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        try {
            return $this->client->request('GET', 'https://api.url./something', [
                'headers' => [
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key' => $this->apiKey,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ]
            ]);
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to send request to api', 0, $e);
        };
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Example;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class ResponseDecoder
{
    public function decode(ResponseInterface $response): \stdClass
    {

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        if ($response === null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to decode api response');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Example;

class ResponseValidator
{
    public function isValid(\stdClass $response): bool
    {
        if (is_array($response) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($response as $array) {
            if (!isset($array['leagues'])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Example;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ResponseParser
{
    /**
     * @param \stdClass $response
     * @return Collection[]
     */
    public function toCollection(\stdClass $response): array
    {
        $collections = [];
        foreach ($response as $array => $val) {
            foreach ($val['leagues'] as $id) {
                $collections[] = collect($id)->except(['coverage'])->toArray();
            }
        }
        return $collections;
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Example;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class LeagueFactory
{
    public function create(Collection $collection): void
    {
        League::firstOrCreate($collection);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback, much appreciated. I will work on your comments.

Comment: can you provide me with some material to study "how to design code in laravel"?

Comment: I don't have any Laravel-specific sources for you, but you could look into [object design style guide](https://livebook.manning.com/book/object-design-style-guide/) written by [Matthias Noback](https://matthiasnoback.nl/archives/). He has some good ideas regarding clean coding